# C++ using ceil and length outputs incorrect value

Tags: java, c++

This application in Java after receiving the correct input, outputs a number. 
The input1 looks like this:

- 3 2
- 1000
- 1010
- 1999

Output will be: 2

For input2:

- 2 1
- 0
- 1000

Output will be: 1

```
    public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = input.nextInt();
    int k = input.nextInt();
    int[] c = new int[200001];
    for(int a = 0; a < n; a++){
        int b = input.nextInt();
        c[b]++;
        c[b+1000]--;
    }
    int Requests = 0;
    int maxRequests = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a < c.length; a++){
        Requests += c[a];
        if(Requests > maxRequests){
            maxRequests = Requests;

        }
    }

    System.out.println((int)(Math.ceil(((maxRequests+0.0)/k) - 0.000000001)+0.2));

}
```

I have made this application in C++ but the problem is that for the input1 it outputs "1" and for the input2 = "2". Which is incorrect.

My Code looks like this:

```
int main() {

    int n;
    int k;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;   
    std::vector<int> c (200001);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int b;
        cin >> b;
        c[b]++;
        c[b+1000]--;
    }

    int Requests = 0;
    int maxRequests = 0;

    for(int a = 0, length = sizeof(c); a < length; a++)
    {
        Requests += c[a];
        if(Requests > maxRequests){
            maxRequests = Requests; 
        }
    }
    int x = ceil(((((maxRequests+0.0)/k) - 0.000000001)+0.2));        
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

I have been trying to solve this for the last 4 hours, and it's now 4AM and I know that I should read a book, I'm asking here like a last resort. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `sizeof(c)` -- What does `sizeof()` do?  It doesn't do what you think it does here.  Also, why not use a debugger?  You would have seen that the loop will not iterate the requisite number of times, indicating that your loop is not set up properly (and thus lead you into doing more research on why `sizeof` doesn't work).

Comment: Please indent your c++ code correctly. Its quite difficult to read with all of those braces everywhere.

Comment: Also, this is why line-by-line translations from Java to C++ will not work if you don't take the time to learn basic C++.  You will end up wasting hours on something simple such as `sizeof`, trying to make it the same as what `length` does in Java.

Comment: In addition to everything else, code such as this: `int x = ceil(((((maxRequests+0.0)/k) - 0.000000001)+0.2)); ` is more than likely not going to give you the same results in Java as in C++ due to floating point calculations not implemented the same way and general issues with floating point not being exact.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: C++ is something new to me. I'm trying to solve a problem, if you google "disastrous downtime" it shows up. I have literally been trying to solve this from beginning of the day till now. Thank you everyone for your input

Comment: @AmandaWood Read my last comment.  Don't use floating point to calculate something that can be done using integers.  Floating point is an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the result should be `2` in both cases. In the second case, the values in the array will be a 1, a -1, and a lot of 0's. The maximum is 1. 1-0.00000001/1 +0.2 = 1.199999999 (give or take a 9 or two). That's clearly more than 1, and less than 2, so `ceil` will round it up to `2`.

As far as implementing it in C++ goes, I'd probably do the job somewhat differently. In particular, I'd take advantage of a few of the standard algorithms to handle part of the job for me. Part of what you're doing:

```
for(int a = 0; a<c.size(); a++)
{
    Requests += c[a];
```

...is what `std::partial_sum` already does. The trick is that `partial_sum` takes an iterator to tell it where to deposit its results. Now, we could (for example) write the results to a vector, then scan through the vector to find the largest item:

```
std::vector<int> maxes;

std::partial_sums(c.begin(), c.end(), std::back_inserter(maxes));

int maxRequests = *std::max_element(maxes.begin(), maxes.end());
```

At least to me, it seems rather wasteful to write an entire vector of values when we really only want one: the largest one that we've seen so far. One possibility would be to create an iterator to do that (I know this is longer than anybody would like--fortunately, it's mostly just boilerplate so don't need to care much about for the moment:

```
template <class T>
class keep_max_t {
    T *val;
public:
    using iterator_tag = std::output_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = void;
    using difference_type = void;
    using pointer = void;
    using reference = void;

    keep_max_t(T &t) : val(&t) {
        *val = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    }

    keep_max_t &operator=(T new_val) { 
        *val = std::max(*val, new_val);
        return *this; 
    }

    keep_max_t &operator++() { return *this; }
    keep_max_t &operator++(int) { return *this; }
    keep_max_t &operator*() { return *this; }
};

template <class T>
keep_max_t<T> keep_max(T &v) { return keep_max_t<T>(v); }
```

Now we can compute the partial sums, and keep the maximum value more directly:

```
int maxRequests;

std::partial_sum(c.begin(), c.end(), keep_max(maxRequests));
```

Now let's take a look at the calculation you're doing:

```
int x = ceil(((((maxRequests+0.0)/k) - 0.000000001)+0.2));
```

Starting from the middle: `(maxRequests+0.0)` is basically just a somewhat strange way to get the value of `maxRequests`, but converted from `int` to `double`. We want a double (or at least *some* floating point type), because the next step is to divide the result by `k`.

We do do that a little more simply though: make `k` a `double`, and when we do `maxRequests / k`, the compiler will automatically convert `maxRequests` to `double,` and do the division in double precision floating point math. So, we can simplify that much down to:

```
double k;
cin >> k;

// ...

int x = ceil((maxRequests/k) // ...;
```

From there, things get truly strange--for reasons I still don't quite fathom, we subtract one number, then add another number. We can just add those together ahead of time, to get:

```
std::ceil((maxRequests / k) + 0.199999999);
```

Finally, we all know that multiplication and division have higher precedence than addition and subtraction, so we can remove the extraneous parentheses, so this turns into:

```
std::ceil(maxRequests / k + 0.199999999);
```

I'm still not sure what the magic `0.199999999` means, but other than that magic number it's now fairly readable.

Of course, we also undoubtedly want to do that computation in a function instead of just shoving everything into `main`.

For easy testing, however, we *can* put the test input values into `main`, and feed them to our function (and print out the result). Putting all that together, we might end up with code something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include "keeper.h"

int compute_result(std::istream &input) {
    int n;
    double k;
    input >> n;
    input >> k;
    std::vector<int> c(200001);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int b;
        input >> b;
        c[b]++;
        c[b + 1000]--;
    }

    int maxRequests;

    std::partial_sum(c.begin(), c.end(), keep_max(maxRequests));

    return std::ceil(maxRequests / k + 0.199999999);
}

int main() {
    using std::cin;
    std::stringstream input1{ "3 2 1000 1010 1999" };
    std::stringstream input2{ " 2 1 0 1000" };

    std::cout << "First result: " << compute_result(input1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Second result: " << compute_result(input2) << "\n";
}
```

...where "keeper.h" contains the iterator shown above.